# explain vue-router component as a function

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I have seen in several different places the following type of route definition:

```
{   path : '/dashboard',
    component: { render (c) { return c('router-view') }},
    children:[{
            path:"",
            component: Dashboard
        }]
},
```

I am trying to understand how this is different then

```
{   path : '/dashboard',
    component: Dashboard
},
```

I think it is related to the optional addition of child routs (e.g. /dashboard/user) so that and the children array here just explains that the Dashboard component renders the path /dashboard whereas if I had the second piece of code then it can only render /dashboard.

What I do want to know is what exactly this does

```
    component: { render (c) { return c('router-view') }},
```

I assume this is some form of a degenerated component but I don't understand what exactly does it do and how.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Vue, a component is created using an object containing its configuration.

The simplest possible component may look something like this

```
componentConfig = {
    template: '<div>test</div>'
};    
Vue.component('test', componentConfig);
```

In some cases, a developer might not want to use `template`, and would want to create element from scratch using pure Javascript. That's where render function comes in.

> Vue recommends using templates to build your HTML in the vast majority
> of cases. There are situations however, where you really need the full
> programmatic power of JavaScript. That’s where you can use the render
> function, a closer-to-the-compiler alternative to templates.
>
> from https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#Basics

To change the example above to using render function:

```
componentConfig = {
    render: function(createElement) {
        return createElement('div', 'test')
    }
};
Vue.component('test', componentConfig);
```

They would produce the exact same result:

- https://codepen.io/jacobgoh101/pen/ZoKwKb?editors=1010
- https://codepen.io/jacobgoh101/pen/PemVmy?editors=1010

In other words, **`render function` is simply an alternative to using `template`**.

```
{
    component: {
        render(c) {
            return c('router-view')
        }
    }
}
```

is equal to

```
{
    component: {
        render(createElement) {
            return createElement('router-view')
        }
    }
}
```

is equal to

```
{
    component: {
        template: `<router-view></router-view>`
    }
}
```

Because render function is `closer-to-the-compiler`, it's faster compared to using template. That's probably why the author of your code does it this way.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @jacob-goh Can you check this question too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58606395/how-to-use-slots-in-router-view

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the rest of your code, but it looks like this might be an implementation of the [vue-router Lazy Loading functionality](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/lazy-loading.html). Basically, Vue + Webpack are going to split your code into chunks and only load those chunks whenever the user attempts to navigate to those routes, rather than loading them all and creating a bigger bundle to download than necessary.

> When building apps with a bundler, the JavaScript bundle can become quite large, and thus affect the page load time. It would be more efficient if we can split each route's components into a separate chunk, and only load them when the route is visited.
>
> Combining Vue's async component feature and webpack's code splitting feature, it's trivially easy to lazy-load route components.

Comment: This analysis of yours is true (it is part of the template I am using), but how does it answer my Q ?

Comment: If you read the link that I provided, then you will see that it demonstrates how Lazy Loading works.

Comment: unfortunately, this is not Lazy Loading Component (Async Component)

Comment: @JacobGoh => Then please post some more of your code. Without knowing what the `render` function does, then I can't do much more. My answer was just a shot-in-the-dark guess as it was. :(