# Conditional route in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, single-page-application, vue-router

I have two different views that I'd like to show for the same path depending on whether a token is in LocalStorage or not. I could move the logic directly into the view itself, but I was curious to know whether there's a way to it in the Router.

Something like:

```
export default new Router({
  mode: "history",
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/",
      name: "home",
      component: function() {
        if (...) {
          return ViewA
        } else {
          return ViewB
        }
      }
    },
  ]
});
```

I tried with the above code but didn't work. The app builds fine but none of the two views is shown.

Answer (score 9):

A getter could be used for this, but, you will need to be sure to import both components:

```
import ViewA from '@/views/ViewA'
import ViewB from '@/views/ViewB'

export default new Router({
    mode: "history",
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    routes: [
        {
            path: "/",
            name: "home",
            get component() {
                if (...) {
                    return ViewA;
                } else {
                    return ViewB;
                }
            }
        },
    ]
});
```

In my notes, I have written "cannot find documentation on this" pertaining to the above. While not specifically related, however, it might be helpful to review using some information from https://stackoverflow.com/a/50137354/3261560 regarding the render function. I've altered what is discussed there using your example above.

```
component: {
    render(c) {
        if (...) {
            return c(ViewA);
        } else {
            return c(ViewB);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but `components` cannot be functions / arrays etc - only `object`. If `components` _can_ be functions - can you provide a doc link? It will help me a lot too if that's true.

Comment: I've updated my answer with some additional information that might be helpful. My notes say "cannot find documentation". However, you can see how the render function works in the SO link. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50137354/3261560

Comment: Again, this is one of those cases where "it works" but not really something that I'd normally do. It does answer the question directly, but, there are more correct way to handle the desired result. My answer "works" even if it's not something that would be best practice.

Comment: The documentation says that componentes can be Promises, but that after the Promise is fulfilled the component is cached.

Answer (score 3):

I was answering the same question before and you can see it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54133557/fully-dynamic-vue-router/54275453#54275453).

Here is an example:

```
routes: [
    {
      path: '*',
      beforeEnter(to, from, next) {
        let components = {
          default: [A, B, C][Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) % 3],
        };
        to.matched[0].components = components;

        next();
      }
    },
```

... where A, B, C are components and they are randomly chosen every time the route changes. So in your case you can just alter `beforeEnter` logic to your needs and set any component you wish before routing to it.

Answer (score 3):

Alright so I found a simple way to do this using the webpack lazy loading functionality in vue router with vuex store state property;

```
{
  path: '/',
  component: () => { 
    if (store.state.domain) {
      return import(/* webpackChunkName: "app-home" */ '../views/AppHome.vue');
    } else {
      return import(/* webpackChunkName: "home" */ '../views/Home.vue');
    }
  }
},
```

With the above code, my home component is dynamically imported and used the route component depending on the value of **domain** property in my vuex store. Please note that you have to set up vuex store and import it in your router for this to work.

The solution in the question would have worked if you returned the component as an import.