# Vue Router: if the argument to next() and to are equal, why isn't navigation confirmed?

Tags: vue-router

I find my beforeEach function filled with checks to see if the value of `to` matches the value that will be passed to `next()` to prevent infinite loops. For example, if I wanted to send the user to login if they weren't logged in, I can't use:

```
if (!user.isLoggedIn) {
    return next({ name: 'login' });
}
```

Instead I have to use:

```
if (!user.isLoggedIn) {
    if (to.name !== 'login') {
        return next({ name: 'login' });
    }

    return next();
}
```

To me, this seems odd and needless. Is there something that I am missing about how I should be using Vue Router? Is there a use-case for calling `next()` with the same argument as the current value of `to`?

Answer (score 0):

One of the patterns followed for this, is including a [meta property on the route itself](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/meta.html), and then checking if that property is set in the hook:

```
If(!user.isLoggedIn && to.route.meta.requiresAuth) 
    next({name: 'login'});
else
    next();
```

And since your login, register and forgot password pages does not require authentication, you break the loop

Comment: This is a helpful pattern that I do use when I'm not trying to make a simple example ;) It's not, however, an answer to the question of why I'd  ever want to call next() with an argument identical to `to`.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: because `next`-function has different meaning (objectives).

> `next`-function is like a dispatcher who is telling the train where to
>   go.

Calling `next`-function with the same `to`-route has meaning only when the app state is changing between these calls (cookies were removed, localStorage values changed, session ended etc), otherwise you receive an infinite loop warning / error.

> Is there a use-case for calling next() with the same argument as the
>   current value of to?

Yes, there are some use-cases. One of them can be found in this [SO quesion and answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54133557/523630) - dynamically change a component that is responsible for view rendering.

Comment: This is very insightful. Any recommendations on how to get around writing an infinite loop check for nearly every call to next with arguments?

Comment: @meetalexjohnson, you can check if `to === from`. If they are the same - you have an infinite loop (if there won't be any additional checks, redirects, query or params changes). But any solution depends on your final task.

Comment: `from` is always the same, no matter how many times you loop through, so that will not prevent an infinite loop.