# How to use slots in router-view

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm trying to use slot in router-view and unable to get the slot data in child component.

I search a lot, this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/m3ptm9j7/9/) seems to work in single js file. 
But, when I use slot in separate file component, it doesn't work for me.

I'm using vue": "^2.1.2" and "vue-router": "^3.0.2"
I have tried this code:

AppContainer.vue

```
<router-view>
  <p> This is a default slot</p>
  <p slot="test"> This is a named slot</p>
</router-view>
```

ComponentA.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    ...
    <slot/>
  </div>
</template>
```

ComponentB.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <slot name="test"><slot/>
    ...
  </div>
</template>
```

route.js

```
{
  path: '/performance',
  redirect: '/performance/evaluator',
  component: {
     render(c) {
       return c('router-view')
     }
  },
  children: [
     {
       path: 'evaluator',
       name: 'ComponentA',
       component: ComponentA
      },
      {
        path: 'management',
        name: 'ComponentB',
        component: ComponentB
      }
   ]
}
```

I'm getting no slot data in both components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slot can work in `router-view`, that's for sure => https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-routing-example-14843

I believe what went wrong is the way you config the routes, especially

```
 component: {
     render(c) {
       return c('router-view')
     }
  },
```

if you want the parent component to render nothing, it would be simpler to separate the path config

```
[
  // ...
  {
    path: '/performance',
    redirect: '/performance/evaluator',
  },
  {
    path: '/performance/evaluator',
    name: 'ComponentA',
    component: ComponentA,
  },
  {
    path: '/performance/management',
    name: 'ComponentB',
    component: ComponentB,
  },
];
```

Comment: @jacob-joh You are right the issue was in the above mentioned block. I'm able to fix this by using: 
component: {
            template: `<router-view> <slot/> </router-view>`
          }